# returning to regular for loop after async event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, aiogram

I am making a flashcard telegram bot with aiogram library and have a problem. I use a regular for loop to go through the list of flashcards. There is a Finite State Machine, which suppose to wait for the users command to show front (/next) and back (/flip) of a card.

My problem is, that after these events i can't return to my regular loop and continue with other flashcards, so they are only shown one by one, after user types in /show_today_cards.

How can i fix this?

Here is a part of my code with these functions:

```
class ShowCard(StatesGroup):
    NEXT = State()
    FLIP = State()


# Запуск повторения, команда /show_today_cards
async def show_today_cards(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    cards = db_get_today_cards(user_id)
    
    await message.answer('Начнем повторение на сегодня!\n Введите команду /next')
    for card in cards:
        await state.set_state(ShowCard.NEXT)
        await state.update_data(front=card[1])
        await state.update_data(back=card[2])
        await state.update_data(card_id = card[0])
    
    if not cards:
        await message.answer('Ha сегодня карточек нет')
        return


# Показ передней стороны, команда /next
async def show_front(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(ShowCard.FLIP)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer('Показываем переднюю сторону карточки')
    await message.answer(data["front"])
    await message.answer('Введите команду /flip, чтобы увидеть заднюю сторону карточки')


# Показ задней стороны, команда /flip
async def show_back(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(data["back"])
    await message.answer('Введите команду /next, чтобы перейти к следующей карточке')
    card_id = data['card_id']
    db_update_card(card_id)
    await state.finish()
```